# Monitoring SSH authentication with Nagios

Tags: ssh, nagios

As the title suggests, I would like to remotely monitor SSH authentication (not just TCP service) on a remote host.  Occasionally, this host likes to have the service running but refuse logins through PAM.

There is check_ssh, which only monitors the TCP service, and there is check_by_ssh, which executes a remote command via ssh for monitoring purposes.  I could hijack the latter, but it requires pub key authentication.  I need to monitor with a plain SSH login.  I realize the security implications.

Is a custom Nagios plugin that executes SSH my best bet?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, you can always run `check_by_ssh` (via pub key) and then run `true`

Comment: That's a sensible direction, although I really need to use interactive (password) auth to test the thing I'm emulating.  I think maybe something with sshpass and true might do it?

Comment: I never done it, but I guess you can also you `expect` but then again that'd be something completely custom script.

Comment: It might be helpful (and easier) to just look for PAM failures in auth.log or /var/log/messages or equivalent